# jquery filter multiple <ul> <li> find values and also debugging

Tags: jquery, dom, filter

I am a newbie using backbone views and trying to debug.  I have form validation that populates
new `<ul>` and `<li>` tags when there are errors and before I will only send form data to the back end if I haven't made any of these new elements. I need to check for them.  I found this to show what my input fields are set to:

```
$('input').each(function(){console.log($(this).attr('id')+'  '+$(this).val());});
```

I read about traversing the DOM

```
var listItems = $( 'ul' );
var special = listItems.filter( 'li' );
```

This finds the first `<ul> <li>` group up in the navigation

I need help scanning the DOM for these new and perhaps multiple `<ul> <li>` tags that
I create  HTML from chrome with errors is supplied.    THANKS!

```
<div class="nav-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav" id="navbutts">
        <li class="" id="homebutt"><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li id="weddingbutt"><a href="#weddings">Weddings</a>
        </li>
        <li id="dancesbutt"><a href="#dances">Dances</a>
        </li>
        <li id="contactbutt"><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li id="registerbutt" class="active"><a href="#register">Register</a>
        </li>
        <li id="bookitbutt"><a href="#bookit">Book it</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">More<b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#owner">The Owner</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#equipment">Equipment</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#consulting">Event Consulting</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#testimonials">Testimonials</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#testimonialinks">Testimonials link</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="control-group warning">
    <label class="control-label required" for="loginnameconf">Confirm Email</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <div class="input-prepend" data-role="acknowledge-input">
            <div data-role="acknowledgement" class="add-on" style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0);"><i class="icon-warning-sign"></i>
            </div>
            <input type="email" data-type="email" required="required" placeholder="Confirm email" maxlength="254" name="loginnameconf" id="loginnameconf" class="inputclass pageRequired input-xlarge" data-validation-match-match="loginname" data-validation-match-message="Emails must match"
            aria-invalid="true">
            <span class="loginnameconf_error label label-info hide"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="help-block">
            <ul role="alert">
                <li>Not a valid email address    // this was added to the DOM
                    <!-- data-validator-validemail-message to override -->
                </li>
                <li>Emails must match</li>    // this was added to the DOM
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group warning">
    <label class="control-label required" for="password">Password</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <div class="input-prepend" data-role="acknowledge-input">
            <div data-role="acknowledgement" class="add-on" style="color: rgb(0, 255, 0);"><i class="icon-ok"></i>
            </div>
            <input type="password" required="required" placeholder="Password" minlength="6" maxlength="16" name="password" id="password" class="inputclass pageRequired input-medium" data-validation-minlength-message="6-16 characters required" data-validation-maxlength-message="6-16 characters required"
            aria-invalid="true">
        </div>
        <span class="password_error label label-info hide"></span>
        <div class="help-block">
            <ul role="alert">   // this was added to the DOM
                <li>6-16 characters required</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>


// I can't seem to combine the filter and the .each to find the <ul><li> elements
   I added 

// shows names and values for form input text boxes
$('input').each(function(){console.log($(this).attr('id')+' '+$(this).val());}); 

var hasError = false; 

$('ul li').each(function(index){ 
    if( $(this).text().length !== 0 ){ 
        alert('Client side error found'); hasError = true; }
});
```

Comment: You should not be using the dom to figure out if your form has validation errors; you should use whatever function is checking to see if an input is invalid. A good place for this would be that backbone view that you mentioned.

Comment: I AM using two validation libraries- bootstrap-acknowledgeinput and jqBootstrapValidation - the view has used them to generate these new <ul><li> elements, now what I am doing is trying to detect the presence of these new DOM elements and if I find them STOP the form from posting to the back end. So two flavors of client side validation have already been run. The HTML above is taken from the chrome debugger - it's not original DOM, it's the DOM modified after validation has taken place – I can't figure out how to find those new <ul><li> elements using filter etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find that either one of these validation libraries sets a "validated successfully" flag for me to use.  Therefore, I needed to determine the presence of new

tags

```
I needed to scan for this:

     <div class="help-block">
        <ul role="alert">
            <li>Not a valid email address    // this was added to the DOM
```

this does it

```
  $('div.help-block ul').each(function() {
     //alert('AHHHHHH!');
     hasError = true;
 }); // end each

 then later:

 if (hasError)
    { return false; }
  else
    {
    registermodel.save();
    return false;
        }
```